# Cannot create and open PDF using JAVA android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I would like to create a PDF document using the PdfDocument API.  So to do this, i have created a demo function called `getTicketAsPdf` and this also has a sub function called `addText` to add text to the pdf document.

All seems to run, but when the Choose File dialog appears and i select Adobe Reader, i get an error message saying

> This file could not be accessed. Check the location or the network and
>   try again

I understand that documents saved in your application need to have a Uri generated using the `FileProvider` which i have done, and this works for CSV files that i generate using a `StringBuilder`, but not for the PDF, so i dont think the problem is with my `FileProvider`.

Here is the code

```
private void getTicketAsPdf() {
    try {
        int width = 595;
        int height = 842;

        // create a new document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // crate a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width, height, 1).create();

        // start a page
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        // get canvas
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        // get color
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

        // draw header square
        canvas.drawRect(25, 25, width - 25, 50, paint);
        addText(canvas, "MY HEADER", "#ffffff", 100, 50, 50, 1);
        addText(canvas, "And some simple text", "#FF0000", 25, 100, 100, 1);

        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);

        // write the document content
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "test.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        document.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
        document.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        // make file available
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider", file);
        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        target.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");

        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
        context.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void addText(Canvas canvas, String text, String color, int size, int x, int y, int align) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    paint.setTextAlign(align == 0 ? Paint.Align.LEFT : align == 1 ? Paint.Align.CENTER : Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    //paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setTextSize(size);

    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
}
```

As i said i have already setup my `FileProvider` and this works on another function, but just encase something is different for PDF, here it is

res\xml\file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_files" path="" />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:authorities="com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```